# Quarkus: How to define and read properties file (or application.properties) outside application or at runtime?

Tags: quarkus, mail-sender

In Quarkus, We have properties file inside project itself called application.properties.

Is there any Quarkus way to define external properties file in my use case like i am developing a mail sender and i want to add recipients in future.

Is it possible to give application.properties outside at local and inject it at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a configuration file in your application working directory under `config/application.properties` : https://quarkus.io/guides/config#overriding-properties-at-runtime

There is ongoing discussion to have more *runtime configuration capabilities* here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1218

Comment: @loicnathieu: It appears, it does not support runtime picking configuration from external location, i need to write property file reader etc for same.

Answer (score 3):

As loïc says, you can follow the convention and create a `config/application.properties`. You can also use the property [`quarkus.config.locations`](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#quarkus-config-config_quarkus.config.locations) to specify additional config locations. It can be defined at runtime like below

`java -Dquarkus.config.locations=app-config/config.properties -jar my-app.jar`

Comment: Hi, How can the application properties be loaded from an external JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by keeping .properties (or .yaml) in [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html).
It's really easy to set it up. It's is well documented in following link (official documentation):
[Quarkus - Reading properties from Spring Cloud Config Server](https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-cloud-config-client)